# Ecto - accessing datetime fields by month

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

```
defp query_by(query, %{"min_end_date_month" => min_end_date_month} = params) do
  query = from(q in query, where: q.end_date.month <= ^min_end_date_month)

  query_by(query, Map.delete(params, "min_end_date_month"))
end
```

The query function above is returning this error: `(Ecto.Query.CompileError) q.start_date().year() is not a valid query expression`. However, in the iex console, I can normally do `some_record.end_date.month` since `month` is a valid key. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a query returns a Date value to Elixir, Elixir decodes it into a `Date` struct, which lets you access the parts of the date using `.year`, `.month`, etc. A query is executed by the database though, where you can't access the year/month/day with a `.`. There are database specific functions to extract these values from a Date value. Assuming you're on PostgreSQL, you can use `date_part`:

```
query = from(q in query, where: fragment("date_part('month', ?)", q.end_date) <= ^min_end_date_month)
```

Comment: Hi, I encountered this error after modifying my query:
`Postgrex expected a float, got "11"`

Comment: Is `min_end_date_month` a string? I think you need to do `^String.to_float(min_end_date_month)`.